# How to stripoff the string after space, slash (/), greater than (>),dot(.) in shell

Tags: regex, perl, shell

I need to strip-off the data which comes *after* space , slash `/`, greater than `>`, dot `.`. I only need to display the part before the space, slash, dot, greater than symbol in given string data using a shell or Perl script.

ex:

```
a15-ap-5035.wma.ibm.com
a15-ap-99995/wma.ibm.com
a15-ap-99995>wma.ibm.com
```

Comment: note this is not the first question you ask. Try to read [ask] to see how to format properly and, eventually, accept the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In shell you can do string manipulation:

```
s='a15-ap-99995>wma.ibm.com'
echo "${s/[,\/. >]*/}"
a15-ap-99995>wma

s='a15-ap-5035.wma.ibm.com'
echo "${s/[,\/. >]*/}"
a15-ap-5035
```

Using `perl:

```
perl -pe 's~[,/>. ].*~~' <<< "$s"
```

Comment: Can you please tell me , how to use in perl with syntax

Comment: Using perl you can do `s~[,/>. ].*~~`

Comment: Please mention with the sample example,

Comment: I already add code in my answer i.e. `perl -pe 's~[,/>. ].*~~' <<< "$s"`

Comment: HIi, I tried with this solution,it works fine                                                                                                              my $string='a15-ap-99995.wma.ibm.com';
 $string =~ s/[\/\s>.(].*//;

 #print $string;

Answer (score 2):

> stripoff the data which comes after  space, slash (/), greater than (>),(.),

In Perl it would be like,

```
$str =~ s/[\/\s>.].*//;
```

Comment: s='a15-ap-99995>wma.ibm.com' ;   
system("~ s/[\/\s>.].*//;");  Is it correct syntax in perl?

Comment: How to write into the file after parsing?

Answer (score 2):

Using [Bash Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
s="a15-ap-5035.wma.ibm.com"
echo "${s%%[./> ]*}"
```